# Weblogic set JDBC Shared

Tags: database, jdbc, weblogic

I'm using Weblogic and I set a JDBC driver to allow a service to get a connection to the db.
 This DB is also reachable by other clients for other purposes.
What I want to do now, it's to make the JDBC connections "**SHARED**" with the other clients that connect to the database.
I read that the follow syntax let me achieve this:
`jdbc:oracle:thin:<USER>/@(PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = <HOST>)(PORT = <PORT>)))(CONNECT_DATA = (SID = <SID>) (SERVER = SHARED)))`
and would let me have the JDBC connections shared with the others regular connections.

Is it true ?
Where to set such parameters in weblogic ?

I'm currently using the JDBC driver ( SERVICES->JDBC->DATA SOURCES-> connection pool (tab) ) configured in the following manner:

URL:
 `jdbc:bea:oracle://[dbIP]:1521`

Driver Class Name:

```
weblogic.jdbc.oracle.OracleDriver
```

Properties:

```
user=ETL
portNumber=1521
SID=LIVDEV1
serverName=[dbIP]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The URL of Oracle should be jdbc:oracle:thin:@[host][:port]:SID.
No need to set these parameters in properties again, but you need to set the user
And for password, WebLogic already provides a standalone field for it. It will be encrypted by WebLogic.

You can reference http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/jdbc/programming.html#1053561